Conditional variance of random walk with given start points and ending points
If I have a random walk with 0 drift and I observe that $X_1 = x_1$ and $X_k = x_k$, bu I don't have all the points from $X_i$ for $i \in \{2, ..., k-1 \}$, how do I estimate them and given an CI? I know that the expected value will just be the linear interpolation from $X_1$ to $X_k$, how about the conditional variance? It will be smaller than the intrinsic variance of the random walk, but I am not sure by how much. Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

What do you know about the variance of this walk?  If it's nothing, then you have exceptionally little information to estimate it -- just one value, $(x_k-x_1)^2.$

I have many such points with missing data between and I estimate variance by $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \frac{(x_{t_{i+1}} - x_{t_i})^2} {t_{i+1} - t_i}$
